Building two flavors of a library with cmake
Let's say we have a library A which is our core functionality and used everywhere. We then executable B which depends on A and executable Test which also depends on A.
There are two flavors of A: production A and testing A. The only difference between the two flavors is how file Testable.cpp is compiled - for testing A it is compiled with -DWITH_TESTABLE. All the other files in A are compiled in the same way for production and testing.
The question is: is it possible to make CMake compile B with production flavor of A and compile Test with testing flavor of A, without CMAKE recompiling library A two times (it should only recompile Testable.cpp that has different compilation flags).

You need to create two library targets (two add_library calls). If you don't want to compile twice source files except Testable.cpp, then create OBJECT library from those files. That intermediate library could be linked with both of library targets.
